# How to keep the shape of columns in a dataframe object intact after shuffling one of the columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a `DataFrame` object called `df` which is formed by tabulating 6 numpy (N, ) and (N, 3) arrays as columns of the table:

```py
data = {'ID': ids_data.tolist(), 
        'Position': positions_data.tolist(), 
        'Radius': radiuss_data.tolist(), 
        'Mass': masss_data.tolist(), 
        'Velocity': velocitys_data.tolist(), 
        'Escape Velocity': escape_velocitys_data.tolist()}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Here is the form of `position_array` before being put into `data`: i.e. a shape of (N, 3) array

```py
[[ -36.12  -51.06  222.9 ]
 [-211.2    21.56  215.1 ]
 [-215.3   -36.88  175.9 ]
  ...
 [ 181.9    53.9   185.1 ]
 [ 145.1   156.4   159.  ]
 [ -16.59   11.52  165.8 ]]
```

I shuffled one of the columns of the table this way:

```py
df['Position'] = df['Position'].sample(frac=1)
```

Now, I need to retrieve all columns of the new `DataFrame` object in the form of either (N, ) or (N, 3) `numpy arrays` for later use in the script.

```
ids_data, positions_data, radiuss_data, masss_data, velocitys_data, escape_velocitys_data = df['ID'].values, df['Position'].values, df['Radius'].values, df['Mass'].values, df['Velocity'].values, df['Escape Velocity'].values
```

However, after printing `position_array,` here is the output: e.g. a shape of (N, ) array

```
[list([9.32, 6.92, -9.669]) list([67.61, 116.6, 35.13])
 list([149.4, 107.3, 159.8]) ... list([79.3, -44.27, 0.03649])
 list([19.0, -13.63, -16.86]) list([140.0, -177.1, 104.0])]
```

Could you please teach me how to get rid of "list" word and maintain the format of the array as it was before being used for the table, i.e. (N, 3) `numpy array`?

Comment: You could try `np.vstack(position_array)`.  That word `list` isn't just a pretty decoration!  It means the array contains lists, instead of being a `(N,3)` array of floats.  Usually this is the result of trying make an array from a mix of items such as lists of different size.  `np.array(...)` tries to make a multidimensional array if it can.  An object dtype array is a fall back option.

Comment: Thank you for your reasoning! it's appreciated.

Comment: @FBruzzesi, thank you for the edit